nginx does not display photo
have nginx installed and running Ok. But I don't get any response (i.e. times out) from Firefox on another box with the URL of https//johnrose.mywire.org/summer.html. That URL has a certificate created by Certbot which also modified the johnrose.mywire.org file Ok in /etc/nginx/sites-available/.When I double click the summer.html file on the nginx box it displays Ok in Firefox. I have the nginx full ports (i.e. 80 & 443) open (in ufw) on the nginx box and the router Port Forwards 80 & 443 to the nginx box. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?
summer.html is in the johnrose.mywire.org 'root' directory:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><b>Summer the Cat</b></h1>
<br>
<img src="../images/summer.jpg" alt="Summer" width="400" height="300">
<br>
<p><b>Life is so hard</b></p>
<br>

</body>
</html>

summer.jpg is in images directory of johnrose.mywire.org 'root' directory.
Here is johnrose.mywire.org server block:
# Virtual Host configuration for johnrose.mywire.org
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
server {

    server_name johnrose.mywire.org;

    root /home/manager/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/johnrose.mywire.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/johnrose.mywire.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = johnrose.mywire.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name johnrose.mywire.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

If the images directory is in the doc root and summer.html is in your doc root then your img src should be "/images/summer.jpg" or "images/summer.jpg"

If your images directory is outside of the doc root, you cannot trick Nginx into serving that file for you, otherwise you could use /../ on any web server to get at every file in the system. Add another location to point to your images folder.

The appropriate lines from the server block for johnrose.mywire.org are:
root /home/manager/www/html;
index index.html;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
@Richard Smith My feeling is that I should change the above root to /home/manager/www and add an alias or location both for the html sub-directory and for the images sub-directory (of the root directory). Is that correct?

Are you going to change src="../images/summer.jpg"? Usually, if you want to serve images from /home/manager/www/images/, you would use src="/images/summer.jpg" and add location /images { root /home/manager/www; } - but that's just one way to do it.

I've decided  that I would like html & images sub-directories in the root directory (i.e. /home/manager/www). So I've tried using alias as follows:
server {
server_name johnrose.mywire.org;
root /home/manager/www;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /html/ {
alias /home/manager/www/html;
index index.html
try_files $uri $uri/ /html/index.html;
}
location /images/ {
alias /home/manager/www/images;
}
But that doesn't work.

Apologies for not using Code facility in question.
